# Are the following functions in O(x³)?

Tags: big-o, asymptotic-complexity

I'm trying to decide whether the following functions are or can be `O(x³)` assuming `k = 1`. I have what I think are the right answers but I'm confused on a few so I figured someone on here could look over them. If one is wrong, could you please explain why? From what I understand if it is about `x³` then it can be referred to as `O(x³)` and if its below it can't be? I think I may be viewing it wrong or have the concept of this backwards.

Thanks

```
    a. 3x = TRUE
    b. 10x + 42 = FALSE
    c. 2 + 4x + 8x² = FALSE
    d. (logx + 1)⋅(2x + 3) = true
    e. 2x + x! = TRUE
```

Comment: `2x+x!` will be `O(x!)`. the O() always refers to the LARGEST/FASTEST growing component of the function in question. x! will grow very very very much faster than x^3 ever could. logx+1 is false as well. that's just simple math and multiplication. it's O(x) at best, maybe O(xlogx)

Comment: This is not really a programming question. But write down the definition what O (x^3) means. It's almost, but not quite exactly the opposite of what you are saying. As a result, almost all of your answers are wrong.

Comment: Yes but if it grows faster then it can be x^3 but if it grows slower it can't be correct? So anything growing faster then x^3 can be x^3 or do i have that backwards?

Comment: No. Neither of them.

Comment: @MarcB D. is correct, it's O(x logx) which is O(x^3).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### What is meant by Big-O?

A function f is in O(g), if you can find a constant number c with f ≤ c·g (for all x > x<sub>0</sub>).

#### The results

1. `3x` is not in `O(x3)`, due to `limx → ∞ 3x/x3 = ∞`
2. `10x+42` is in `O(x3)`. `c = 52` holds for all `x ≥ 1`.
3. `2 + 4x + 8x2` is in `O(x3)`. `c = 14` holds for all `x ≥ 1`.
4. `(logx+1)(2x+3)` is in `O(x3)`. `c = 7` holds for all `x ≥ 1`.
5. `2x + x!` is not in `O(x3)`, due to `limx→∞(2x+x!)/x3 = ∞`

Answer (score 1):

Think of `O(f)` as an upper bound. So when we write `g = O(f)` we mean `g` grows/runs at most as fast as `f`. It's like `<=` for running times. The correct answers are:

```
a. FALSE
b. TRUE
c. TRUE
d. TRUE
e. FALSE
```